# Copy Row in Pandas when Condition is met into a new Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have been trying for a few hours on my own now without advancing much, so I come to you to help.

Assume I have a Dataframe with Index and 4 attached columns:

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'df': [0, 0,0,1,0], 'cba': [np.nan, 696,1021,146,np.nan],'Availability_150': [2.26,36.2 ,70.15,40.78,11.4],'max_av_alt': [100,120 ,140,135,130]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Now, whenever there is a nan value in the cba column I want that **entire** row moved/copied to another DataFrame. The Goal is to have two different dataframes, one that contains all the non nan-Values of cba and one that contains all the nan-Values.

To figure out whether I have a nan value or not I need to put in:

```py
np.isnan(df_result.iloc[:,1])
```

But I have absolutely no Idea:

```py
df_result_nan['cba-nan'] = df_result[df_result['cba'] == np.isnan(df_result.iloc[:,1])]
```

This gives me only nan values in the new dataframe

```py
df_result_nan['cba-nan'] = np.isnan(df_result.iloc[:,1])
```

This gives me only the True/False mask for cba...

I hope you can help me, I have been working for some time now with DataFrames but there are so many aspects I still seem to can't understand.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_result_nan['cba-nan']     = df.loc[ df['cba'].isnull()]
df_result_nan['cba-not-nan'] = df.loc[~df['cba'].isnull()]
```